# Не получается развернуть сайт написанный на Laravel на хостинге

Tags: php, laravel, хостинг

Всем привет. Не думал что столкнусь с проблемой при разворачивании проекта на хостинге но вот)

Загрузил сайт на рег.ру в папку `www/сайт`, вроде как нужно почистить кеш после. Но любая команда artisan выдает такую ошибку `file_put_contents(D:\OpenServer\domains\links\storage\framework/sessions/671Rq8vWv3KBnxqqyD10woEYMtyGeN73TGynOb7x): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory` и соответственно кеш почистить не получается.

Попробовал руками удалить папку `storage/framework/cache` в итоге толку никакого.

Но вот что интересно, каждый раз когда я захожу на главную страницу сайта, у меня в папке `/www/chrry.me/public/` генерируется две директории `D:\OpenServer\domains\links\storage\debugbar` и `D:\OpenServer\domains\links\storage\logs`. Удаляю, а они снова появляются.

Comment: Непонятно.. Пишите, `Загрузил сайт на рег.ру` и потом сразу про ошибку с путём OSPanel (`D:\OpenServer`).. Что-то где-то явно не так делаете, проверьте все добавленные конфигурации

Comment: права выдайте на запись в директории storage/* куда сессия пишется для начала. А дебаг бар свой отключите потом не забудьте.

Comment: В bootstrap/cache/config.php прописаны настройки с Open Server, при удалении этого файла вообще ничего не работает, даже ошибку не показывает